# Verb for 'retrieval of wealth'

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember finding this word in P. Spufford's *Power and Profit*, and now can't read it without once again fruitlessly checking reverse dictionaries.

It was used to describe a mass revival of investment after a downturn, and was either in the context of, or specifically referred to, removal of money stored in chests. I doubt it was divest or another common word; it could well have been a compound of re-, dis- or de-.

Answer (score 1):

Your title does not correspond to your question. "Retrieval of wealth" does not have the same meaning as "mass revival of investment after a downturn". Which one are you looking for ?

If it's the latter it could be

> [recovery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recovery)

1: the act, process, or an instance of recovering; especially : an economic upturn (as after a depression) (WEBSTER)

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the retrieval of gold from their hope chests after a sizable drop, then perhaps you're thinking of a *redemption*. Definition 5 at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redemption) includes the notion of something repurchased that had been sold.

Here are two uses of *massive redemption.*

1. [Massive Redemptions, Strong Dollar Squash Goldbugs](http://slant.investorplace.com/2013/03/strong-dollar-and-massive-redemptions-squash-gold/)
2. [Ex-SAC Trader Stefan Frank Shutters His Hedge Fund FISAM Capital After Massive Redemption](http://www.businessinsider.com/fisam-capital-hedge-fund-closes-2011-3#ixzz2RrCDqwqI)